# Automatic cropping of pictures

Tags: scripting, image-processing, automation, tiff, image

I have many pictures that are made of an object with black background. I've created them with Matlab, and they all have a white "extra" surrounding the picture. I want to be able to automatically crop them so that the picture will not have the white extra.

The files are `.tif` format

Here is a picture as an example:[image]

It may be not noticeable at first, but if you select the picture, it's much bigger than just the black area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply throw away the rows and columns in which you have only ones.

```
%# read the image
[img,map] = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyz8Z.png');

%# keep only rows/cols that have values other than 1
img = img(any(img<1,2),any(img<1,1));
```

For RGB tiffs, you can use (assuming that the max value in the tiff image is 86, as in the png)

```
img = img(~all(all(img==max(img(:)),3),2),~all(all(img==max(img(:)),3),1),:);
```

---

**EDIT**

There are a few ways to ensure that you don't get the border in the first place. For example, if you want to save an M-by-N-by-3 RGB image array, you can use [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) to write

```
imwrite(imageArray,'myFile.tif')
```

Alterantively, if you have a figure you'd like to save without the border, you can call [GETFRAME](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html) on the axes handle to obtain the image:

```
axesHandle = gca; %# to get the axes handle of the current figure
f = getframe(axesHandle);
imwrite(f.cdata,'myFile.tif');
```

If you want to save your figure with anti-aliasing, you can use the excellent [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) from the file exchange.

Comment: A. It produces a gray scale picture and I lose the colors.


B. When I save it it still adds the white surroundings.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed: Sorry, I assumed that white was 255. It looks like your maximum value is 86 only. Also, I forgot the colon at the end.

Comment: @Jonas, It still keeps the white frame, and when I save it It adds one if it didn't exist already.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed: It's a bit tricky to know what exactly your tiff image looks like, my code works fine on the png. However, I've tried a solution that should work in general.

Comment: I have no problem uploading the file somewhere for examination. But I think that the answer will not come from Matlab, When I save in Matlab, it automatically adds the white margins, what I hope for is some script that will automatically do so with `gimp` or any other photo manipulation program.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed: In that case, you may want to save your figure differently, so that Matlab doesn't automatically add the white border. See my edit.